# BBpress - No topics & reply post_type accessible for admin users

Tags: plugins, buddypress, bbpress

I'm using the default theme of WordPress(Twenty Twenty) & only plugin used is bbpress and buddypress. Now if I access topics & replies in backend It shows "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit posts in this post type."

Backend URL: https://xxxx.org/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=reply | https://xxxxx.org/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=topic

Ref: https://prnt.sc/hqOHY4WI5Wpd